# Generate list in place of 'false'

Tags: prolog

This post is about prolog programming in general, not specific to swi-prolog.

```
floor_locations([ 0.0, 0.17, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.83, 1.0 ]).
    
cabin_location_is_reached( cabin_location, floor_location, true ) :-
   abs( cabin_location - floor_location ) =< 0.01.
cabin_location_is_reached( cabin_location, floor_location, false ) :-
   abs( cabin_location - floor_location ) > 0.01.
    
list_floors_to_be_served( [], [],_, [] ).
list_floors_to_be_served( 
   [request|floor_requests],
   [floor_location|floor_locations],
   cabin_location,
   [has_to_be_served|floors_to_be_served_list] ) :-
   cabin_location_is_reached( 
      cabin_location,
      floor_location,
      has_to_be_served ),
   list_floors_to_be_served(
      floor_requests,
      floor_locations,
      cabin_location,
      floors_to_be_served_list ).
```

The question is:

```
list_floors_to_be_served( 
   [ false, false, true, false, false, false, true ], 
   floor_locations, 
   0.33,
   X ).
```

And the expected result should be:

```
[false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
```

The current result is: `false` :-(

How to correct my mistakes?

Comment: In Prolog, variables need to start with an uppercase letter! This program has no variables, only constants.

Comment: This is double posted as [SWI-Prolog Forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/beginner-how-to-generate-a-list-by-recursion/3024?u=ericgt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by David Tonhofer, this programme has no variables. It has other errors such as: (a) in the request, the variable "floor_locations" has no value. After some detective work, here it is:

```
floor_locations([ 0.0, 0.17, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.83, 1.0 ]).
    
cabin_location_is_reached( Cabin_location, Floor_location, true ) :-
   abs( Cabin_location - Floor_location ) =< 0.01.
cabin_location_is_reached( Cabin_location, Floor_location, false ) :-
   abs( Cabin_location - Floor_location ) > 0.01.
    
list_floors_to_be_served( [], [],_, [] ).
list_floors_to_be_served( 
   [Request|Floor_requests],
   [Floor_location|Floor_locations],
   Cabin_location,
   [Has_to_be_served|Floors_to_be_served_list] ) :-
   
   cabin_location_is_reached(Cabin_location, Floor_location, Has_to_be_served),
   
   list_floors_to_be_served(Floor_requests, Floor_locations, Cabin_location,
      Floors_to_be_served_list).
      
go(X) :- 
    floor_locations(Ls),
    list_floors_to_be_served( 
       [ false, false, true, false, false, false, true ], Ls, 0.33, X).
```

I defined the go/1 predicate to retrive the floor_locations parameters needed in the call list_floors_to_be_served/4. The first argument to list_floors_to_be_served/4 is not used at all. And the given request returns:

```
?- go(X).
X = [false,false,true,false,false,false,false]
```

To get X = [false, false, false, false, false, false, true], you need to redefine :

```
floor_locations([ 0.0, 0.17, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.83, 0.33 ]).
```

Quite a curious program.

Comment: This program is a fragment of a control/command program of an elevator of 7 floors. I have made it in Java and  C++. I try to port it in Prolog. Very difficult for me, as I'm an old procedural programmer.

Comment: Hey! I'm 64 going on 65. But I've done some Prolog when I was younger. BTW you can put the answer in your post on SWI-PROLOG forum (I'm limiting myself to SO).